# Get list of orders with increment_id

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I can use the Magento API (https://magento.redoc.ly/2.4.4-admin/tag/ordersid) to get a list of orders using the following endpoint: "rest/V1/orders/items".

However, this endpoint does not return the increment_id, just the order_id. It also doesn't return the order status.

Is there a way to batch get all the orders within a certain period with their corresponding increment_id? And with their status?

The only way I have thoughts of is:

1. Get all the orders with the order_id
2. For each order_id, get the increment_id and status using the following endpoint: "rest/V1/orders/{order_id}"

But this 2nd step is time consuming since it needs to be done for each order, so I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    ..., 
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
){
    ...
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}
$orderId = "your order id here";

$order = $this->orderRepository->get($orderId);
$orderIncrementId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

Comment: but here you are still doing one API request for eacvh order ID... also, I would like to use the REST API.